# How increases the speed Ajax-php-xml chat application?

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I made chat application using Ajax-php-xml technology. It work fine if the number of users below 50.
     otherwise speed of application dramatically decreases. I want to manage 200s users at a time.

**my XML format is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <messageData>
        <message>
        <sender>user__5338</sender>
        <receiver>user__5339</receiver>
        <content>hello</content>
        <date_time>2012-08-17  09:24:57</date_time>
        <status>unread</status>
        </message>
        <message>
        <sender>user__5338</sender>
        <receiver>user__5339</receiver>
        <content>hello</content>
        <date_time>2012-08-17  09:26:21</date_time>
        <status>unread</status>
        </message>
        </messageData>
```

In my php, I fetch data from xml file using this method

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($this->xml_file);
     foreach($xml->message as $chat_data){
         if($chat_data->status =='unread' && $chat_data->receiver ==$username){ 
          $chat_data->status = 'read';
          $xml->asXML($this->xml_file);
          $sender =(string)$chat_data->sender;
          $chat['message'] = (string)$chat_data->content;

          $chat['date'] = (string)$chat_data->date_time;
         }
     }
```

How can inrease the speed of chat application? Can i increase the speed by using node js?

Comment: AJAX is not really suited to this sort of thing, at least optimally. Web sockets are more complex to implement, but might be worth looking into. They were designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use json as ajax transfer data type? I believe it might be faster, because php doesn't need to parse xml. And use jQuery as javascript library for your ajax requests, it is one of the best. It supports json. And use [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/) as an example.

And one more thing, set the interval between ajax requests to 1-3 seconds. Maybe even more.

Answer (score 0):

using sockets could increase your communication speed for sure , it may sound complicated but for your purpose it's the answer. 
sockets are :

> The WebSocket specification defines an API establishing "socket"
>   connections between a web browser and a server. In plain words: There
>   is an persistent connection between the client and the server and both
>   parties can start sending data at any time.

simple example :

```
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
// When the connection is open, send some data to the server
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};

// Log errors
connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};

// Log messages from the server
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
```

searching will give your more examples